# Using axios in a web action in IBM Cloud using node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, ibm-cloud

I've been trying to get a simple web action to make an authenticated GET request to an API (i've removed the actual url, and secrets from example code).

I have run this successfully locally, but when I test the web action, it simply dies after logging "calling axios".

It doesn't report an error, and I have tried to implement a promise thinking that the thread was ending before the api responded, but no effect.  Any pointers?

```
    /**
      *
      * main() will be run when you invoke this action
      *
      * @param Cloud Functions actions accept a single parameter, which must be a JSON object.
      *
      * @return The output of this action, which must be a JSON object.
      *
      */
    function main(params) {
    getData().then(function(result) {
        console.log("In the THEN of original method call");
    return "hello";
        
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("In catch of original method call");
    });
    
        
    }
    
     function getData(){
                    const crypto = require('crypto');
                    const axios = require('axios');
                    const secretKey = "ENTER KEY HERE";  
                    const apiId = 99999;  
                    const apiBaseUrl = "https://acmewebservice.com";
                    const apiPath = "/customer/9";
                    const apiFullPath = apiBaseUrl + apiPath;       
                    const sharedSecretHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(secretKey).digest('hex');
             
                    console.log("In getData");
                    var authToken = apiId + ":" + sharedSecretHash;
            
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    console.log("Calling axios");
                    axios.get(apiFullPath, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authentication': authToken
                            }
                        }).then(response => {
                            console.log("Did this work?")
                            var x = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                            console.log(x);
                            resolve(response);
                      })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log("In Catch")
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                    });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-wrap the axios call, it's already a promise.

The `return` is needed to make the engine effectively wait for the result of the async call.

```js
     function getData(){
                    const crypto = require('crypto');
                    const axios = require('axios');
                    const secretKey = "ENTER KEY HERE";  
                    const apiId = 99999;  
                    const apiBaseUrl = "https://acmewebservice.com";
                    const apiPath = "/customer/9";
                    const apiFullPath = apiBaseUrl + apiPath;       
                    const sharedSecretHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(secretKey).digest('hex');
             
                    console.log("In getData");
                    var authToken = apiId + ":" + sharedSecretHash;
            
                    console.log("Calling axios");
                    return axios.get(apiFullPath, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authentication': authToken
                            }
                        }).then(response => {
                            console.log("Did this work?")
                            var x = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                            console.log(x);
                            return response;
                      })
                        .catch(error => {
                        console.log("In Catch")
                        console.log(error);

                    });
```

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome @PaulGarden! Could you "green check" my answer? Or is that an admin thing? I am just getting back into this site. Thanks!